# What happens if you have more than 1 apple id associated with 1 account...?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, messages

I have an iPhone with my own Apple ID and my daughter has an iPod Touch with her own Apple ID. Am I able to set iMessages syncing so I get my messages **AND** all of her messages sent to my iPhone, without having any of MY messages sent to her iPod Touch? (shes 8)

Would I just add her apple id and password on my phone? Will I then get messages for **both** accounts? And would she still **only**  receive **her** messages like normal, but would **NOT** receive any of my messages?

How would I set that up on my iPhone so all the texting done by me with my contacts are sent from my iPhone, but so that I am also able to view and monitor all her iPod Touch messages?  What will happen if I add her Apple ID to my iPhone?

Will that work?

Comment: +1 for keeping track of her texting. First, unless you put your Apple ID, and password into her Touch, you shouldn't have to worry about her receiving your messages. Second, I would try - no idea if it works, otherwise I would have left an answer - adding her Apple ID into Settings > Messages > Receive at > Add another email. To be honest, I'd be pretty surprised if that would work well, but it would be interesting to give it a try. Let us know how that works.

Comment: No, didnt work. Is it even possible to use 2 seperate Apple ID's (with the 2 seperate email addresses associated with it) for the imessages at the same time?

Comment: Well. The problem is there is nowhere for you to log in to a second Apple ID. Apple has set up iOS pretty well for one user. Unfortunately, I'm coming up basically dry. I would recommend looking around to see if there are any apps that could provide what you want (note, none will be able to see what the Messages app is doing). One other thing you could try if you have an iPad or Mac - set up just your daughter's iMessage account on there. Things should sync well, and you would then be able to see everything.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you want to keep an eye out... but all messages?  and no privacy? ;-)

That said.

What you could try is setting up a extra account (user) on your iMac/Macbook. Hookup her iCloud account there. You can swap between your own account and 'her' account on the fly.

When you then open iMessage on the desktop i think (and expect) that you would find all copies of her iMessages. That is, Apple iMessages, true SMS are not delivered (only on the iPhone). But since she has a iPod Touch... i think you should be safe. Give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

[image: iMessage Configuration Screen]

[image: iMessage Account Screen]

As you can see in the first screenshot, you can set a number of email addresses by which you can receive messages at on your phone. However, as the second screenshot shows, you can only have one Apple ID connected to a device at a time.

You might be thinking, "Ok, can't I just add her Apple ID email address to my phone?"

The answer is no. Any time you add an email address to your iMessage account, the email is verified with Apple. If you attempt to add an email address associated with another Apple ID, Apple will decline it and neither iPhone nor OS X will not allow you to add the email address.

Conclusion: Unfortunately, there is no way to do this with iPhone or OS X. You could do what was previously suggested and set up a secondary account on your Mac (if you have one) and link that account to her Apple ID and use Message there to view the exchanges, but to specifically answer your question, OS X does not accept more than one Apple ID for iMessage per user and iPhone does not accept more than one Apple ID for iMessage either.

Answer (score -1):

go to settings and add your daughters email address